Error Logs Missing with InfluxDB Backend Listener When Running via Maven
I am encountering an issue with error logging when using an InfluxDB backend listener with JMeter. The problem is I'm observing two behaviors when running it via CMD and the JMeter Maven plugin.
Local Execution (Command Line): When I run the JMeter script locally via the command line, the Jmeter error logs are displayed in Grafana as expected as in the below image.
Local execution errors
Execution using Jmter maven plugin: When the same script is executed via the JMeter Maven plugin in Jenkins, the error logs not displayed in Grafana as this image.
Execution using Jmter maven plugin errors
I am running the same script and trying to determine why the error logs are not being published to Grafana when I run it using the JMeter Maven plugin. Is there any configuration that needs to be set in the JMeter Maven plugin?
